# How to send JSON object to rest webservice?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a rest webservice at `http://localhost:8600/rest/student/details` which will update the details of student into database. I have to send the details as JSON format in method post.

The below is the method to generate that json message

```
private void createOrUpdateStudent(WebResource service) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    StudentImpl student= new StudentImpl ();

    student.setId(6);
    student.setName("Godwin");
    student.setSex("Male");     

    StudentView view = new StudentView(student);        

    System.out.println("::::::"+service.path("/rest/student").path("/details").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, gson.toJson(view)));
}
```

where `studentView` class is as below.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="clusterZipcode")
public class StudentView {  

    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public String sex;


   public StudentView() {}

   public StudentView(StudentImpl  student) {
        this.id = student.getId();
        this.name = student.getName();
        this.sex = student.getSex();

   }
```

while sending like above i am getting an error stating `Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Name' cannot be null`

Is i am passing the json values correctly or if there is an alternate method to send the json message please suggest me.

Comment: Can you show what is your StudentView look like?

Comment: i updated the studentview class sandiip.

Comment: it's likely the name property is not getting set on the server where it's deserializing the json back into the object. would be hard to troubleshoot without seeing the full server stack trace. You can't get that?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see on your post where are you doing the call to the database. All I can see is that you are creating a Student and then, from there, creating a view (assuming this method is being called). The error you are getting is related to the fact that, at some point, you are calling the database to enter a new row in (probably) your student Model. If you have got hibernate, can you make sure that you are not calling .save or .update at any point between the call you get for the student and before you call setName?

Comment: The database call are in service side which we dont have access to.

Comment: Are you getting that error on the service? That error is related to a jdbc call to the database which I cannot see anywhere in the call that you posted. If the error is on the server, then we will have to know how is the API supposed to pass the name parameter to the server. Something a bit odd is the fact that your student class has got an Integer as name, if the server is expecting a String it might be blowing up there and failing silently with the other error that you are seeing, although I'd be surprised if it wasn't casting that Integer to a String, since you have to post it anyway

Comment: actually the service was working fine while calling the service method in junit.

my service code is like this

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response createOrUpdate(StudentView student) { }

the student was supposed to have the values but it isn't that is the problem.

Comment: If student is supposed to be an integer, can you change it to int? I just don't get the plan behind converting "Godwin" to an integer, could you explain? If the cast fails it might return null as Integer value... If int, at least zero will be returned by why is it a number instead of String?

Comment: May I suggest you sysout the Gson.tojson of view and put it here so we cAn see what is actually being sent?

Comment: {"id":6,"name":"Godwin","sex":"Male"}

Comment: Can you also post a copy of the JavaScript that you were using to do the Ajax request? Could it be the server is expecting an object with Name instead of name?

Comment: service.path("/rest/student").path("/details").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, gson.toJson(view)  THis is where i call the service there is no javascript or ajax in it.

Comment: You said you had it working with JavaScript before, that is the one I meant :) we don't have access to the Api code so we need to check what worked before

Comment: Oh that is JUNIT. Which is just calling the service method with the model object in it. Like 'createOrUpdate(student)'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34620/discussion-between-user1900662-and-jose-sutilo)